# Unable to start Xserver on Centos7

Tags: gnome, pam, xserver

I am struggling to set a desktop environment on a Centos 7.2 Server. I connect to the server in following way:-

- Though putty ssh onto a jump box with my user Then from the jump box
- ssh onto the Centos 7.2 server using my id

I have installed and tried below desktops:
Gnome Desktop --> Couldn't make it work (finally did a sudo yum groupremove of it)
Cinnamon --> still struggling

Have installed following packages:-

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel -y install cinnamon*    
sudo yum install xorg*
```

I keep getting below error on startx:-

```
xauth:  file /home/ma357577/.serverauth.4007 does not exist  

(EE)  
Fatal server error:  
(EE) PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server.  
        Perhaps you do not have console ownership?  
(EE)  
(EE)  
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support  
         at http://wiki.x.org  
 for help.  
(EE)  
xinit: giving up  
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused  
xinit: server error  
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

I have tried to
rename /etc/pam.d/xserver (but in absence of this it falls back to /etc/pam.d/other hence is completely restricted)
and change the xserver file as below:-

```
\#%PAM-1.0  
auth       sufficient   pam_rootok.so  
\#auth       required    pam_console.so  
auth      sufficient    pam_console.so  nullok  
account    required     pam_permit.so   nullok  
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
```

none of the changes seem to work. Searched a lot on google but still stuck.

Eagerly seeking help on this! Thanks in advance.

Regards
Rohan

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Check out this instruction [Configuring VNC Server](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-TigerVNC.html#sec-configuring-vnc-server)

You want to use xined service.